# visual studio running functions inside the editor problem

Tags: visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

i have my windows form and it has 2 buttons each calling a method which uses a property in a user control to get some data and if the textbox in the user control is empty it shows a messagebox and throws an error. the problem is the code runs even when the application is not running. when i open the form, click on the user control, or change any of the other controls properties the code executes and the messagebox shows up. i tried closing the visual studio but it didn't help.

Comment: What do you have in Load event handler of the user control or its OnLoad method or its constructor?